# Using database specific attributes in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a max value that I'd like a value to never exceed so my intent is to use the least function in Postgresql to ensure that the value doesn't exceed the given limit. How can I use a Postgresql specific function in db.session.query without writing out the entire query manually?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's looking for the same answer at some point - it turns out that using `func` from SQLAlchemy will have allow you to use any function that's built in. So `func.least(a, b)` will compile to `least(a, b)` in SQL;